# Extracting error message from rejected action payload in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to find a concise way to extract an error message that is sent in a rejected action payload. Since there are different reasons for an error, the payload is being populated differently.

For instance, a network (axios) error message can be retrieved as

```
payload.response.data.message
```

in other case it is,

```
payload.stack
```

If there a simple way to extract the message without writing a long if statement verifying `hasOwn` for each sub-level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lodash library. Lodash provides a function called get that simplifies nested property access and handles undefined values gracefully.

```
import get from 'lodash/get';

// Assuming payload is your action payload
const errorMessage = _.get(payload, 'response.data.message', _.get(payload, 'stack', 'Unknown error'));

console.log(errorMessage);
```

Take a reference from lodash official documentation
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get